# TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, csv, flask

I want to retrieve the output csv file from one method to another without downloading the csv file.

The method that outputs csv is given by:

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=['POST'])
def transform_view():
     //Some data analysis stuff
     final['final_predicted'] = final.Converted_prob.map(lambda x:
                                                        (1 if x > 0.5 else 0))

     resp = make_response(final.to_csv())
     resp.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \'attachment; filename= export.csv'
     resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
     return resp
```

Here, I exported the csv as export.csv, but I want this csv in my other method without needing for it to download in my disk, I want this csv in another method to do some visualization stuff.

Method for visualization:

```
@app.route('/transform2', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def transform_view2():
    resp = transform_view()
    print(resp)
    df1 = resp[['Converted_prob', 'Converted', 'final_predicted']]
    chart_data = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
    chart_data = json.dumps(chart_data, indent=2)
    data = {'chart_data': chart_data}
    return render_template("graph.html", data=data)
```

I tried to `print(resp)`, but it doesn't show any output, why is that? I want `['Converted_prob', 'Converted', 'final_predicted']` from the resp. The export.csv file contains these columns, but when I try to retrieve it in method  `transform_view2()` it throws `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `transform_view` returns an object of type `Response`.
This object not only contains the actual response (i.e. CSV contents) but all other information needed for a proper HTTP response.
To get the contents of the response, do this:

```
def transform_view2():
    respobj = transform_view()
    resp = respobj.response
```

Now `resp` contains the content of the response. You can now convert it into a dict.

Comment: Hey, I did   resp = resppbj.response and resp2 = pd.DataFrame(resp), but says  KeyError: "None of [Index(['Converted_prob', 'Converted', 'final_predicted'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is incorrect. The argument to pd.DataFrame , i.e., resp, must be of type dict or iterable. resp = respobj.response => This returns a string. You should first convert it into a iterable or a dict. I don't know the format of your csv; but you could use module csv to convert the CSV string to dictionary. (csv.reader)

Comment: but it says resp  is list not string.

Comment: It must be a list with just single item. That item should be a string. I could be wrong though. Point is; convert the response to a dict and then pass to DataFrame.